# PHP Pdo Help... can't get pdo fetchall to work for me

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to migrate to php pdo... can someone please tell me why on earth this bit of code is not working?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(aw_score) AS awscoreaw, SUM(hm_score) AS awscoreaw_def FROM nfl_new WHERE away=:away AND date<:date AND Season=:season");

$stmt->bindValue(':away', $row['away'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':date', $row['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':season', $row['Season'], PDO::PARAM_STR);                            
$stmt->execute();
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
echo $affected_rows.' ';
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $rows['awscoreaw_def'].' '.$row['away'].'<br />';
```

Comment: what are you getting as result ? nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`away` is not in your select list, and you use `fetchAll`, you need to iterate the result.

```
$rows = $stmt->fectchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo $row awscoreaw['awscoreaw_def'].' '.$row['awscoreaw'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you... fetchAll was the issue.  Replacing with fetch does the trick.